# spring-data-elasticsearcher :How can i use route to delete document in spring data elasticsearcher

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

my child document mapping is:

```
{
"_index": "test-index",
"_type": "test_type",
"_id": "AVznf5cOTLguhbQOC8aV",
"_version": 1,
"_score": null,
"_routing": "1b973ddd-0aa9-4578-9bf9-74125a3c7r4d",
"_parent": "1b973ddd-0aa9-4578-9bf9-74125a3c7r4d",
"_source": {
"id": null,
"email": "test@hempel.com",
"actionDate": "2017-06-20T08:43:52.000Z",
"actionStatus": "SENT_SUCCESS",
"description": "",
"ip": "0.0.0.0",
"address": "",
"browser": null,
"os": "",
"taskId": "1b973ddd-0aa9-4578-9bf9-74125a3c7f4d",
"taskName": "007",
"actionStatusName": "SENT_SUCCESS",
"new": true
},
"sort": [
"test@hempel.com"
]
}
```

you can see, it's child document, so every time i query the document like this:

```
test_index/test_type/AVznWID-TLguhbQOC2Zt?routing=89293986-7d08-4e73-be1e-1ec9e136b440     /Get
```

well , so delete will like this:

```
test_index/test_type/AVznWID-TLguhbQOC2Zt?routing=89293986-7d08-4e73-be1e-1ec9e136b440     /delete
```

but the problem is ,how can i query and delete the document with routing value do this job by using spring data elasticsearcher:
ElasticsearchTemplate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well,i have found a way to resolve this problem,just using:

```
org.elasticsearch.action.delete # "DeleteRequest"
```

in some cases,we have come to rely too much on the tool